# How to constrain static table view controller cells to Safe Area in Swift/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view controller with static cells. I’m running on iPhone X and when scrolling, the cells appear to be behind the navigation bar and unsafe area. What is preferred would be a solid orange color in the unsafe area instead of the image presented below. Is this possible? I can’t move to a table view inside of a view controller, which I would then constrain to the safe area, because my cells are static.

Comment: An UITableView can be inside a UIViewController. Post some code if you can

Comment: How do you set up / color the navigation bar?

Comment: can you show us your constraints?

Comment: @Do2 there are no restraints on the view itself as it is a TableViewController which automatically manages and sizes the table view inside of it from my understanding

Comment: Sorry i completely misread the controller part. I have provided you with a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `Container View`, so add a `View Controller` in your storyboard and put a `Container View` in it-by adding the container view it will automatically create a segue and a view controller delete both.

Now from your `Container View` create a segue to the `Table View Controller` and choose `Embed`.

Last step is to set the constraints for your `Container View`, the most important for your issue is the top one, set it 0 to the safe area.

[image]