# How to Add Bottom Safe Areal to Static UITableviewController ? Not in UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout, uitableviewsectionheader

I used Static `UITableViewController` For Registration Form but In *iPhone X*, XR, i want to ad *Safe area* but it's not affecting in Screen, Any Help would be appreciate.

i added also `footerView` but below footer view space is remaining as it is as shown in image
[image]

Comment: add `tableFooterView`, an empty view of desired height. mind it `tableFooterView`.

Comment: Have you tried this? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51050550/how-to-constrain-static-table-view-controller-cells-to-safe-area-in-swift-ios/51053543

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `tableView's` **`contentInset`** to view's **`safeAreaInsets`**, i.e.

```
self.tableView.contentInset = self.view.safeAreaInsets
```